# Member registration form without third party plugins/add-ons

Tags: forms, registration

I am a newbie to expressionengine. I have EE 2.5.5 purchased version. What i want to know is can i create a member registration form and explicitly ask users to register?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to allow members to register without an add-on is to use the Member module's [registration functionality](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/member/index.html#registration-page). This page is displayed based on your "member" trigger word, uses a completely different set of templates from the rest of your site, and is generally a pain in the ass.

(This is why modules like [FreeMember](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freemember) and [User](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/user) are so popular.)

Comment: @Derek: out of curiosity, why wouldn't EE have a stand alone member registration form/tag?

Comment: @mjr +1 it is for FreeMember :)

Comment: @Abie That is an excellent question to which I do not know the answer.

Comment: @DerekHogue thats a good way to put it :) anyway, thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 3):

You should see here http://www.sidd3.com/stand-alone-member-registration-form-in-expressionengine/

This weblog having the example code for stand alone member registration form without using any third-party add-on.

Comment: thanks. its working :). how to pass member group id through form code input ? Please advise.